# How do I `bundle install` with Chef?

Tags: rvm, bundler, chef-infra

I am using Chef to provision a CentOS 6.5 box and install my Rails 4.0.4 app.

I installed RVM and Ruby 2.1.1

When I `cd my_website`, RVM will set the correct ruby version (gemset).

How do I tell Chef to bundle with the correct ruby version

currently I am using this:

```rb
execute "bundle-install" do
  user "my_user"
  cwd "/home/my_user/website/"
  command "bundle install"
  action :run
end
```

But that is not enougth, it's still trying to use ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 1):

RVM is a shell-based Ruby version manager. Since the Chef Client runs as root, it probably isn't executing the login shell. So things like `.rvmrc` and the actual loading of RVM are ignored. Handling this with Chef is a bit complicated. I would recommend looking at Fletcher's [chef-rvm](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm) cookbook.